# Error initializing USB support: Other error [-99]

Tags: kvm, scientific-linux

I am trying to connect to a virtual machine using KVM on Scientific Linux 7. Scientific Linux is running on vmware. When I attempt to connect to the virtual machine I get an error. How do I proceed with troubleshooting this issue?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but looks like someone had a similar issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/698007/lsusb-unable-to-initialize-libusb-99 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a usb controller to the virtual machine in vmware that I was using KVM and the console connected. [image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried it myself and it was the missing piece. It's not a very common issue as most people probably arent running VMM inside of ESXi but this is the exact solution.